# b+ TREE insertion

Tags: b-tree, insertion-order

[image: **enter image description here**]

QUite confused about how to insert at a root.is it the same like insertion at root and non-leaf nodes?,Thanks

Comment: Same as insertion at leaves and non-leaf nodes

Comment: In a B+ tree, insertion always happens at the leaf level, because that is where all the data resides. The nodes above the leaf level contain only keys that serve to guide the search, which may be copies of actual keys or artificial separator keys (e.g. shortest keys that separate the leaf fence keys, or arithmetic mean for integer keys). The leaf layer is often called a 'sequence set' whereas the internal nodes make up the 'index'. When a leaf splits, a suitable separator key is **copied** up into the index layer (or computed), whereas in B-trees the separator is **pushed** up, not copied.